# Creating web user controls from ascx.cs

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I am trying to create a instance of a user web control from the code behind of another user web control.

using ASP.NET;

```
 placeholder1.Controls.Clear();
            module_userWebControl_ascx slModule = (module_userWebControl_ascx)LoadControl("~/module/module_userWebControl.ascx");
            placeholder1.Controls.Add(slModule);
```

Are there issues with the 2.0 framework?

error: The type or namespace name'module_userWebControl_ascx could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or a assembly reference?)

**Please add namespaces or references to solution.
Other solutions don't contain namespaces and I don't have the reputation to add comments yet.

Comment: Here's a clue: when something goes wrong, it's not the framework. When you've done all the research you can and you're 100% confident it's the framework, it's still not the framework. It's your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like the page you are placing that code does not belong to the same namespace of the usercontrol.

try:

```
(usercontrolNamespace.module_userWebControl_ascx)LoadControl("~/module/module_userWebControl.ascx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UserControl uc = new UserControl();
uc.LoadControl(Server.MapPath("module/userWebControl.ascx"));

placeholder1.Controls.Add(uc);
```

hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Add `<%@ Reference Control="~/module/module_userWebControl.ascx" %>` to your parent control's ascx